# How to extract column title from a dataframe and add it to another dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

My goal is to have my column titles in the small df added to an existing large dataframe without me manually typing the name in.

This is the small dataframe.

```
veddra_term_code    veddra_version  veddra_term_name    number_of_animals_affected  accuracy
335                      11               Emesis        NaN                           NaN
142                      11           Anaemia     NOS   NaN                            NaN
```

The large dataframe is similar to the above but has forty columns.

This is the code I used to extract the small dataframe from dict.

```py
df = pd.DataFrame(reaction for result in d['results'] for reaction in result['reaction']) #get reaction data
df
```

Answer (score 1):

You can pass `dataframe.reindex` a list of columns, consisting of the existing columns and also new ones. If a column does not exist yet in the dataframe, it will get as value `NaN`.

Assume that `df` is your big dataframe you want to extend with columns. You can then create a new list of column names (`columns_to_add`) from your small dataframe and combine them. Then you call `reindex` on the big dataframe.

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"A": [1,2,3], "B": [2,3,4]})

existing_columns = df.columns.tolist()
columns_to_add = ["C", "D"] # or use small_df.columns.tolist()
new_columns = existing_columns + columns_to_add

df = df.reindex(columns = new_columns)
```

This will produce:

```
   A  B   C   D
0  1  2 NaN NaN
1  2  3 NaN NaN
2  3  4 NaN NaN
```

If you do not like `NaN` you can use a different value by passing the keyword `fill_value`.
(e.g. `df.reindex(columns = new_columns, fill_value=0)`.

Comment: Thanks. This added the new columns with data but then deleted the data from the large df.  I need to figure that out.

Comment: You‘re welcome! It’s difficult to understand why your existing data in the large df gets removed, because it should not be the case. You can execute the script I provided and see that the original data is still there. Can you print your existing and new column names? Does the resulting df has the original columns and the ones from the small df – or only the columns from the small df? What do you mean with “deleted the data”? The command should not delete the existing data but only init the new columns with a defined value (like `NaN`).

Answer (score 0):

`df.columns` will give you an array of the names of the columns

Answer (score 0):

```
import numpy as np
#loop small dataframe headers
for i in small_df.columns:
    # if large df doesnt have the header, create the header
    if i not in large_df.columns:
        #creates new header with no data
        large_df.loc[:,i]=np.nan
```

Comment: This can be done more efficiently using list comprehensions `[x for x in df.colnames if x not in df2.colnames]`

Comment: The real answer is hiding in the comments :-)